# Value set from one controller into service to be used on another controller returns no value on page refresh using angular js(new to angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controllers

I have a HTML code

```
<div id="{{item.codeName}}">
    <a class="search-results" href="" ui-sref="app.location" ng-click="vm.setValue(item._id)">{{item.codeName}} </a><br><br>
</div>
```

on `ng-click` from the controller i'm invoking a function `vm.setValue` by passing id to controller1 where i am passing id value to the service to set.

In Controller1

```
 vm.setValue = function(Id){
            service.setId(Id);
    }
```

My Service

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.service('setProperties', function () {
    var _Id = null;
        function getId(){
    return _Id; 
}
function setId(Id){
    _Id = Id;
  }
});
```

I was successful setting the `_Id` into service and getting the Id value into my another controller at once...

In controller2

```
 vm.loadDealDetails = function () {      
setProperties.loadSearchDealDetails(setProperties.getId()).then(function(data) {
            if (data !== null) {  
                vm.dealDetailData.push(data);
                setProperties.setId(vm.dealDetailData._id);
            }
        });
    }
```

In controller2 i'm invoking function `vm.loadDealDetails` on page load where i am getting a data from another function of service `loadSearchDealDetails` by passing id value from `getId` function of service...again from the data response i get the Id value and i am setting it into service...but this works only once in a process

As i load/refresh page function `vm.loadDealDetails` function is invoked but im not getting any value by this `setProperties.getId()` as it goes empty without response....how would i make `getId` working on page load/refresh also
Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the value because when you reload your app, your app is loaded again and so `js` files are reloaded as well. So, its as good as fresh app.

Now, you can do below things to keep hold of the data:

1. Assign value to `localStorage`. [Check this link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and implement using angularJS way.
2. Use server `session` to retain the data even after app reload.

Comment: @HKI345 : Great ! wc